# Unable to login to PiranhaCMS after setup

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, piranha-cms

I've installed PiranhaCMS on an existing ASP.NET MVC5 application. Part from I had to install AutoMapper, the installation went through smouthly. I followed the Get Started instruction in the "Adding Piranha CMS to an existing application". I've tried using existing database, the incluede CE database, and event with a new database. It all comes down to the same problem, I get routed to "/manager/install" where I set up the admin user (which gets added to the sysuser table). After this I get routed to the "/manager" page where I get to sign in with the user i just created. When logging in, I get back to the same page. I assume, the user is not valid... but I get no exception or other information.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

try to remove this node in your web.config

system.webServer/modules

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was removing the system.webServer/modules like mentioned above and also changing 
system.web/authentication mode="None"
to /authentication mode="Forms"

Answer (score 1):

The authentication mechanism for the manager uses Forms authentication. Since you just get routed back to the login I'm guessing Forms auth isn't enabled so the cookie doesn't get set!

Answer (score 0):

Removing system.webServer/modules will disable the way MVC application (such as in defulat template) manages loging in users. Having authentication mode to "Forms" is part of getting started tutorial.

It is quite possible (and is in my case) that replacting authentication is not desired behaviour.

The question is how to let those two authentification mechanisms live side by side. I know that we'll have to keep users separated. That is fine. But how to run run two authentications side by side?