# Where does one get Piranha CMS's SQL Server CE sdf data file from?

Tags: sql-server-ce, piranha-cms

I am trying to add Piranha CMS to a simple website. Being Entity Framework and following the [getting started guide](http://piranhacms.org/docs/introduction/getting-started) I thought that the database would be created. I chose to use the file based database which the system is obviously not finding. Am I missing some step?

See error below:

> The database file cannot be found. Check the path to the database. [ Data Source = C:...\App_Data\Piranha.sdf ]

Update 7/6/2017: I installed SQL CE Tools and manually created an sdf file with the name matching the connection string. The app now showed an error about a missing table which I was able to "fix" by setting 'showDBErrors' to false as I found [here](https://github.com/PiranhaCMS/Piranha/issues/429). I will try installing again from the CMS's home page.

Answer (score 0):

So, for me right now the answer is, you have to create your own database (unless someone provides a different/better answer). 
I went ahead and manually created the sdf file in my App_Data folder. After doing that the following error appeared:

https://github.com/PiranhaCMS/Piranha/issues/429

The error with the missing table sysparam seems to be only related with this setting at this point: 
`<showDBErrors value="false" />`
 Setting it to false solved the problem.

Finally I was able to run the setup and be redirected to the login page. Only that I couldn't pass the login page. 
The answer to that particular problem was to [remove the modules section from web config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28391248/unable-to-login-to-piranhacms-after-setup) in my case. Removing the section altogether presents other questions on it's own, but it got me to actually being able to create content.